# TinyMCE image insertion troubles

Tags: php, tinymce

I've decided to use TinyMCE as the text editor on my site and I even bought a licence for Image Manager. All's good, except for one thing.

When I try to insert an image into the text area by clicking the image icon in the tool bar I get a popup with a dialog where I can press another button to select an image with the Image Manager. I was able to configure the Image Manager to look into the correct directory for images. After selecting an image the Image Manager dialog closes and I'm brought back to the initial image selection dialog. In the Image URL field there is now a URL, unfortunately, the URL seems to be wrongly constructed.

The selected image lives in a directory called `images` and the file name is e.g. `picture.jpg`. The domain of my site is `http://mydomain.com`. The constructed Image URL in the dialog becomes this:

```
http://mydomain.comges/picture.jpg
```

It looks like a concatenation accident of some sort. It's clear that something has gone wrong here but with the plethora of TinyMCE settings I have a hard time figuring out what.

I've looked in the Image Manager plugin config file and I tried passing various init parameter to the editor init function, but nothing seems to make a difference. I'm at a point that I'm not sure what to do next.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is a boolean setting - 'convert_urls' - that i seem to recall playing with when i came up against something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that but nothing really seems to make a difference. I went and tried various things from this page: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#Paths.2FURLs_are_incorrect.2C_I_want_absolute.2Frelative_URLs.3F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many config options indeed.
Some entries in the tinymce forum might be relevant to your problem:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=22175

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=24755

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=23221

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=21935

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=21723

If one of those do not help you i suggest you write an own entry into the tinymce forum. The developers of tinymce (moxiecode) do sell the Image Manager plugin, so they have a stronger reason to give support in the forum than for other tinymce questions. You may search for post too using keywords like "Image Manager path".

Comment: Thanks! This one pointed me in the right direction: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=24755

Answer (score 0):

When you set the rootpath, you must also set preview.wwwroot as the difference from root of your site and relative path.

i.e.

```
<add key="filesystem.rootpath" value="D:\site\mysite\public\imagemanager\" />
<add key="preview.wwwroot"     value="D:\site\mysite\" />
```

you get

```
<img src="/public/imagemanager/file-name.jpg" />
```